# How to open/close window of VirtualBox VM at will?

Tags: command-line, virtualbox, window

### Need

I run a VirtualBox VM and would like to programmatically open and close the VM window at will from command line (say, clicking on some icon in a dock that runs a command line).

I'm **not** talking about *minimizing* the window. I want the WM to switch between headless and windowed mode.

The fact is, we're close to it!

- The headless->windowed case is an easy command line.
- The windowed->headless case can be done interactively, I want to do that **purely from command line**.

### Search before posting

One can [open the VM headless](https://superuser.com/questions/1221592/is-it-possible-to-hide-the-window-of-a-virtualbox-vm-until-it-has-finished-start):

```
VBoxManage startvm testVM --type headless
```

and then [show the window](https://www.virtualbox.org/ticket/16093):

```
VBoxManage startvm testVM --type separate
```

(Incidentally, naming that "type" suggests that type does not change, and those command line change type, but anyway...)

### But how to hide from command line?

One can interactively hide the window by clicking the close gadget and selecting "continue in the background".

But I can't find how to do that **from command line** without that interactive menu.

#### Non-solution

I know there's a [SDK](https://www.virtualbox.org/sdkref/) to [download](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads), but that's probably at least an order of magnitude more complex to implement that those simple command lines.

Comment: Does the window have its own executable that can be ended? I don't really have an idea how to solve this problem, but that's the first place I'd check if Oracle didn't include a specific vboxmanage command to end the head session.

Comment: Yes, reading up on --type seperate, it states this is running in a different process, which means you should be able to identify the executable name or the PID for this and end it. The question is whether ending this process by killing the executable would have a negative effect on the VM. Perhaps this behavior is by design, to require you to end your session on the VM from within the VM.

Comment: I tried the "killing executable" option. At first it closed the window as expected. The VM apparently continued to run. But from that on, attempts to get back a window showing graphical output of the VM (even using main VirtualBox window) did not work as expected, until VM was switched off then on. In summary, killing process responsible for display is not really an option.

Answer (score 1):

> I run a VirtualBox VM and would like to programmatically open and close the VM window at will from command line (say, clicking on some icon in a dock that runs a command line).

What I ended up doing is running the VM in headless mode at all times, but enabling the VirtualBox-provided RDP server (part of the Extension Pack).  Then, instead of switching between headless and windowed, I just launch and quit a RDP viewer with proper authentication setup.

There are some limitations with this solution:

- The graphical performance is certainly not as good as with a regular windowed VM display, but since my use case does not need any high-performance graphics (no 3D or video inside the VM) that's okay.
- Adjusting desktop definition is not as straightforward as with regular windowed VM display. Again it's okay here.

Calls to a VirtualBox-specific API may provide something more finely integrated, but it was not needed so far.